# Wildcard Sub Domain Path Issues

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

I have an htaccess rewrite for wildcard sub domains which rewrites foo.domain.com to domain.com/index.php?id=foo. This is done using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? index.php?id=%3 [L]
```

This works OK, but all content on the site is referenced to the root e.g:

```
 "/content/imgs/logo.jpg" or "/ajax/upload.php"
```

The wild-card sub domain changes the root and all content is referenced to:

```
"http://foo.domain.com/content/imgs/logo.jpg"
```

And the content cannot be found because it is not located on this subdomain.

I know you can use the html < base > tags to place a prefix on all href locations but this does not help in javascript for ajax requests.

Is there anything that can be done in htaccess to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please clarify... files on domain.com are being redirected to foo.domain.com/(content/imgs/logo.jpg)? Or they are on foo.domain.com in the first place and not properly redirecting? It would be helpful if you could post at least 3 examples of other urls that aren't working right, and a few that do work right (if any)

Comment: Sure. To clarify, all content is on domain.com. When I use a rewrite rule to pass the subdomain data to my index page, the location of images and other content all use the original foo.domain.com at the root, where the content is not stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think I may have the solution to your problem Christopher!**

Your rewrite condition was being applied to ALL included content such ass css/js/images etc. Which mean it was trying to rewrite this content to index.php?id=%3 instead of style.css.

By adding the line **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f** above the condition and placing the entire condition at the bottom of the htaccess means that it will only apply to files/directories that DO NOT EXIST (i.e. only to wildcard subdomains).

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://domain.com/index.php?id=%3" [L,P]
```

Hope this helps you mate!

W.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one problem right away, you aren't specifying a target domain on your rewrite rule. If all requests from any subdomain except www need to be redirected, you should specify that like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=%3 [L]
```

The other problem with this is that you are ignoring the file path after foo.domain.com, so that ALL requests get redirected to domain/index.php?id=foo regardless if the requested file was a page or an image.

A better way might be to give each "subdomain" its own folder, something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)? http://www.domain.com/%3/$1 [L]
```

so a path like foo.domain.com/content/imgs/logo.jpg would point to domain.com/foo/content/imgs/logo.jpg

Comment: Hi WebChemist, thank you for your response. If I use the full target domain: "http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=%3" in the rewrite rule, the modified URL is no longer hidden and the user is shown the full URL instead of foo.domain.com. Any ideas? Thank you, Chris.

Comment: so basically you are trying to give EVERYTHING a vanity URL, using non-existent subdomains?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to keep everything in the subdomain.

Comment: I am having the same problem and really need a solid solution for making sure Images, JS, CSS and AJAX calls all route back to the main root of http://mywebsite.com instead of http://subdomain.mywebsite.com

Comment: well you might be able to get away with it if you setup the subdomain as an alias of www in your httpd or vhosts file, so that www.domain.com and myuser.domain.com both point to the root server folder so the files would actually exist in the shared location, but this might not be practical if you plan to have thousands of users like a username.blogspot.com style site. Beyond that I'd have to do some testing on my server at home...